# Axios post request returns data instead of rendering an error page

Tags: html, node.js, express, axios, ejs

I have this post request:

```
axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "/sessions/add",
    data: {
        session: {
          name: session.session.name,
          date: sessionDateInput.value,
        },
      },
    })
    //redirect back to sessions/add
    .then((res) => console.log(res))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err.response.data));
```

It works fine if all the post data is correct, however, if it is not correct I have an error page in my "views" directory set up,
with that said, my express server isn't able to render `res.render('errorPage')`
and instead of rendering the error page, throws an error in the console.

the post request works fine if I use the html and it is able to `res.render`:

```
<form method="post" action="/route"></form>
```

the error page:
[image]

any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Since the response contains a `html`-document in case of an error, you could replace the current document with its content, e.g.:

```
//...
.catch((err) => document.write(err.response.data));
```